# Another term/phrase for kill two birds with one stone

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

What is another phrase for kill two birds with one stone? Or another term that implies similar meaning?

Comment: Have your cake AND eat it!

Comment: "twofer" or "Two for One" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-fer

Comment: Eradicate a duality of endothermic feathered vertebrates utilizing a singular particle of naturally-occurring crystalline composite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an old, idiomatic expression which might be used for more than two results of the action:

> one fell swoop <sup>[per wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_fell_swoop)</sup>

Answer (score 10):

To expand upon @Josh61's answer, there are a number of choices mentioned in J. Ray's "[A Complete Collection of English Proverbs](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=VuhDAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&pg=GBS.PR1)", ([page 214](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=VuhDAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&pg=GBS.PA214)) including

- to stop two mouths with one morsel
- to get two son in laws with one daughter
- to kill two flies with one slap.
- to make two friends with one gift
- to take two pigeons with one bean
- to carry two faces under one hood
- to have two strings to one bow

Comment: At least on my computer, neither of your links shows anything but a blank page. Is there perhaps a systemic problem with using links that run through Google Play?

Comment: @SvenYargs thanks for pointing that out - it looks like the links require one to be logged in to a google account.  I'll try to find an alternative.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest **"fill two needs with one deed"**

Edit:
Although I couldn't find it in any dictionary, it's current usage.

[**Hyattsville Life & Times**](http://hyattsvillelife.com/facilities-assessment-may-fill-two-needs-with-one-deed/)

[**nimble**](http://www.nimble.com/blog/5-underrated-types-of-business-videos/)

[**Winspire News**](http://blog.winspireme.com/4-ideas-for-selecting-auction-trips-based-on-location#.VfmN9BFVhBc)

Answer (score 8):

**Twofer** is  the short form for "two for one."

- Definition: *Arrangement in which a single expense or amount of effort produces two returns; Person or thing that has two desirable attributes normally present singly, i.e. something that satisfies two criteria or needs simultaneously*.
- Example: *Going to a wedding in New Orleans during Mardi Gras was a twofer*.

> `EDIT: I realized that @user662852 had already made this proposal :(.`

Answer (score 3):

There is the outdated saying ***[stop two gaps with one bush](https://books.google.it/books?id=uEM_viK7i4AC&pg=PT1060&lpg=PT1060&dq=stop%20two%20gaps%20with%20one%20bush&source=bl&ots=lc8mY_jF5r&sig=B9RdoGme8I-5uRgoYa8UCJcgYGk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMIq9CX3uj7xwIVC7UUCh3Z6gAu#v=onepage&q=stop%20two%20gaps%20with%20one%20bush&f=false)***:

which is the equivalent, probably earlier version of 'killing two birds with one stone'.

(Allen's Dictionary of English Phrases)

Answer (score 3):

In my granola years in Portland, Oregon

**Feed two birds with one seed.** It was regional at that time; I'm not sure if it's spread.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a non-colloquial phrase, the second bird`s demise was a "***positive externality***" of the stone ricocheting off the first bird. Or, if you prefer, it was a ***synergistic side-effect***...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be :

**as a bonus** or **on top of** or **extra benefit**

also, but even less directly you might stretch towards **side effect** etc

Yes these generally refer to additional benefits resulting from what looks like a focus directed at only 'one of the two birds' , yet this approach is very common ... and very very frequently the reality is that on the surface a given plan ~will~ seem more directed at one target yet happen to include the other.

Answer (score -1):

These are close:

- A win-win situation.
- The best of both worlds.

They both relate to achieving two goals at once.

Comment: I don't think a 'win-win' is equivalent.  A win-win, indicates that both sides of a transaction benefit. In the case of killing two birds, the birds don't benefit. 'Best of both worlds' means that you can ​enjoy two different things at the same ​time.  I agree, that that is quite close to the OP's phrase.

Comment: Please add sources or citations for your answer.