# Other terms/ phrases for "hit two birds with one stone"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm trying to find a more pleasant way to express this phrase. Hitting two birds with one stone is a disturbing way to express what I'm trying to say, in my opinion.

Comment: Duplicate: [Another term/phrase for kill two birds with one stone](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/274369/71848)

Comment: _Pull two carts with one donkey._ Trouble is, some people will start to feel sorry for the donkey.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> to achieve two things at once

which is the meaning of the idiom *[to kill (not hit) two birds with one stone](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/kill-two-birds-with-one-stone)*

By the way, since *kill two birds with one stone* is an idiom, its meaning has nothing to do with birds, or killing birds. Native speakers use the idiom all the time and do not think about killing birds. The *meaning* of the idiom is what I have given above, and that is what native speakers think of when they say this idion. An exception could be if they were applying the idiom to an actual situation in life in which two birds were killed with one stone, or one bullet, or something like that. Or for some reason a native speaker slows down and thinks  about the literal meaning, but this would probably be meta-communication and meta-phrasing and not part of regular communication.